# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/zzc.class

Tags: android, exception, build, duplicates, transform

My app is running on an android device . It is showing no error while building the app .However , it gives an exception when i am trying to build an APK for the app .

This is my app.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.delluser.oshoguide"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions
        {
            exclude 'META-INF/notice'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
 }

 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
   }

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have already tried changing the version of firebase libraries from 11.0.1 to 10.2.1 , but it did not work. I have done Clean and Rebuild . However , i am getting the same error.

My Error is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class
```

Comment: Ok. Let's try one thing for testing purpose. Remove this library compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1' from your project and try to build the apk.

Comment: @R.R.M I will try

Comment: @R.R.M it gives error im using the client library

Comment: Just try to comment that part for testing purpose.

Comment: If it does the trick then try to change client library version or try to change services library version to 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

did u try to refresh your project?(in android studio) if not check right hand side there is gradle option open it and select the first option(refresh all projects).

Comment: Tried it , still same result